# Google Charts API - QR code with leading zeros

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-formula, qr-code

I am inserting the following into cell A1 - generate a QR code from the text in both B1 and B2:

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" & B1 & "%0A" & B2)
```

An example might be

B1= TAG
B2= 000000501

I am using a formula for other cells to add one to create an automatic number sequence based on the first value (e.g., `B4=SUM(B2+1)`; `B6=SUM(B4+1)`, etc.).

I would like the resultant QR scan to read "TAG000000501", but the leading zeros are not displayed (e.g., "TAG501". I know how to have the leading zeros displayed regularly by inserting an `'` at the beginning of the number, or by changing the cell type to text or a special format with those six leading zeros. It seems the formula forces it to be a number in the API, which results in dropping the zeros.

Any ideas?

Thanks much for your time!

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about the situation of `I would like the resultant QR scan to read "TAG000000501", but the leading zeros are not displayed`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? By the way, in your tags, `google-apps-script` is included. Does your goal include the method using `google-apps-script`?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_patterns) will help.

Comment: @DaImTo It is enough to go on. `=image()` formula makes the api call to Google charts and returns a qr image link, which is downloaded and the QR image is displayed in a sheets cell. Consider reopening the question.

Comment: Without the api call, what does this return? `="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" & B1 & "%0A" & B2`. Does it return all `0`s?

Comment: I believe the API call must be made for generate the image. I've tried to not call the API and it returns an error.

Comment: @NathanLord What is the string returned? Or what is the error(hover on the error)?

Comment: @NathanLord How many leading zeroes? Or how much padding do you need? You can always use `REPT(0,N)` to add leading 0s and convert to a number using `--` or `VALUE`.

Comment: @TheMaster It results in a formula parse error.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz this is a database, so the number of leading zeroes will change as the values increase. Currently I have seven numerical spaces (max 9,999,999)

Comment: After exploring this a bit more, I don't know how to diagnose at which step in my process the leading zeroes are being dropped - either due to my formula or the Google API.
I'm happy to provide more information if anyone is willing to help with this!

Comment: @NathanLord When you got that Formula Parse error, you didn't put two `=`'s in front, did you? Sometimes I accidentally do that.

Comment: This doesn't return parse error: `="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" & B1 & "%0A" & B2`

Comment: @TheMaster No, but it does not generate an image of the QR code, either.

Comment: Just enclose that  formula in `=image()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" & CONCAT(B1;REPT("0";9-LEN(B2));B2))`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.